# What is the best way to numerically integrate this function?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, improper-integrals, dirac-delta

I am trying to numerically evaluate an integral that came up in my work. The integral takes the form

$$
\int_0^{\infty}dx\tanh(\alpha(x-x^*))\int_0^{\infty}dzf(x,z)\delta(g(x,z)-\beta t(z))
$$

with $\delta(...)$ the Dirac delta function. It is straightforward to write some code to find a $z^*$ such that $g(x,z^*)-\beta h(y^*)\approx0$, but the code takes awhile to solve the expression. I have tried using an approximation for $\delta()$, taking it as the limit of narrower Gaussians, but I found that I could not choose a sufficiently small width parameter, given the actual numbers that go into these expressions. I found a little more success with equation 2.2 from [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1943), but I find that varying $n$ by orders of magnitude changes my results by orders of magnitude, which I would not expect after a sufficiently large $n$. Does anyone have any advice for tackling this integral? I'd prefer to use the `scipy` module in `python` if possible.

Comment: I assume the integration variable of the second integral is $y$? The Dirac delta function property [Composition_with_a_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function) seems applicable here, but this requires knowing the roots of $g(x,y)-\beta h(y)$ which would seem to be dependent upon $x$ as well as $y$. Also, it might help if you define the functions $f(x,y)$, $g(x,y)$, and $h(y)$.

Comment: The left integral factor seems to be infinite. Am I missing something? Or is this question just about computing the right integral?

Comment: @StevenClark see my edit to the expression in the prompt. To get a little more specific with the $z$-dependence, $f(x,z)\propto1/t^3(z)$ with the cosmological time $t(z)=\frac{1}{H_0}\int_z^{\infty}\frac{dz^*}{(1+z^*)E(z^*)}$ where $E(z)$ is defined [here](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Hogg/Hogg4.html) and $g(x,z)\propto\sqrt{r(z)(1+z)}\frac{r(z)}{t(z)}$ with $r(z)$ the proper distance $\frac{1}{H_0}\int_0^z\frac{dz^*}{E(z^*)}$

Comment: With respect to the comment by @whpowell96 above, could you please clarify if this is the product of two integrals or the nested integral $\int\limits_0^{\infty} \left(\tanh(\alpha(x-x^*)) \left(\int\limits_0^{\infty}f(x,z)\, \delta(g(x,z)-\beta\, t(z))\, dz\right)\right) dx$?

Comment: Ah I didn't consider that. I agree some clarification would be helpful.

Comment: @whpowell96 It's meant to be a nested integral. The $x$ dependence in $f,~g$ is not particularly troublesome, but makes the $\tanh()$ integral managable